# Custom deserialisation of JSON field using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm using Jackson to deserialize some JSON and I've run into some trouble while trying to use a custom deserializer for one of the fields.

```
class MyClass
{
    private static class SpecialPropertyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<SpecialProperty>
    {
        @Override
        public SpecialProperty deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
                                           DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
        {
            // do some custom deserialisation
        }
    }

    private static class SpecialProperty
    {
        private String m_foo;

        private String m_bar;

        @JsonCreator
        SpecialProperty(@JsonProperty("foo") String foo,
                        @JsonProperty("bar") String bar)
        {
            m_foo = foo;
            m_bar = bar;
        }
    }

    private String m_identifier;

    private String m_version;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = SpecialPropertyDeseializer.class)
    private SpecialProperty m_specialProperty;

    @JsonCreator
    MyClass(@JsonProperty("identifier") String identifier,
            @JsonProperty("version") String version,
            @JsonProperty("specialProperty") SpecialProperty specialProperty)
    {
        m_identifier = identifier;
        m_version = version;
        m_specialProperty = specialProperty;
    }
}
```

and this is the JSON I want to deserialize:

```
{
    "identifier" : "some-id",
    "version"    : "1.7",
    "specialProperty"    : {
        "foo" : "str1",
        "bar" : "str2"
    },
}
```

I invoke the mapper as follows:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);   
return objectMapper.readValue(input, MyClass.class);
```

I've observed the following behaviour:

1. Without a special property it all works fine - i.e. remove all
   references to `SpecialProperty` from the code and the JSON.
2. If I include `SpecialProperty` in the JSON but remove the custom
   deserializer for it then it also works fine. The ctor for
   `SpecialProperty` is called.
3. With the custom deserializer it doesn't work. The ctor for `SpecialProperty` is called but the custom deserializer is not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does your specialProperty is object? and if yes then what kind of it is?

Comment: It is an object, yes. It's represented by the class `SpecialProperty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@JsonDeserialize` annotation can be placed on a field, a setter or a class. Jackson will take it into account if what is annotated is what it uses to set the value.

E.g.1 It will notice `@JsonDeserialize` over a setter if it uses the setter to set the value of a field.

E.g.2 It will notice `@JsonDeserialize` over a field if it directly sets this field without using a setter or a constructor.

It will tend to take it into account if it's on a class unless it's overridden by a more specific annotation on a field or setter [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html). I reckon the docs could be clearer on the above details.

In your case you have the annotation over the `SpecialProperty` field but you are setting this field in the `MyClass` constructor so it's ignored.

In this case you can move `@JsonDeserialize` over the class instead of over the field. That's probably the simplest solution in your case. E.g.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyClass.SpecialPropertyDeserializer.class)
private static class SpecialProperty {
```

Or you can skip the annotation altogether and register the deserializer on the mapper. First make `SpecialProperty` and `SpecialPropertyDeserializer` non private in `MyClass` and then:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(MyClass.SpecialProperty.class, new MyClass.SpecialPropertyDeserializer());
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

You can also get rid of constructor of `MyClass` and the current annotation over the `SpecialProperty` field will be taken into account.

Comment: is there a way to use the deserializer only for one field but without updating the POJO ?